# не могу импортировать базу данных flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема в файле app.py
прописал для создания БД

'''

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///newICD.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)


@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True)
```

'''

Далее захожу в yf PyCharm в консоль python прописываю
`from app import app, db`
в результате

```
from app import app, db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DB\Desktop\acid\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DB\Desktop\acid\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\DB\Desktop\acid\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 355, in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

Comment: Добрый день, получилось разобраться в проблеме?